# Как из скрипта PHP подставить выбранное значение в файл XSL?

Tags: php

Добрый день!

В общем, создал файл XML. К нему написал файл XSL. Теперь нужно сделать в PHP, чтобы при вводе цвета (green, red, bluе, etc...) значение менялось бы в самом XSL файле:

```
<tr bgcolor="#F5F5F5">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

т.е. на место bgcolor= вставало значение, которое было введено в PHP-скрипте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из PHP нужно передать в XSLT параметры, в вашем случае - значение цвета. Тогда XSLT будет обращаться к параметру по имени - `${PARAM_NAME}` ([`xslt_process`](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.xslt-process.html)).